# Who has winning strategy? Modified from $X + Y$ movie

Tags: game-theory

Recently I watch a youtube video, a scene from $X + Y$ movie, which shows a boy named Nathan solve a problem. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYAahN1G8Y8) is the link to the video.

**Original Problem:** There are 21 cards facing down put in a row. We choose one card that facing down and one card to the right then turn both card. Show that, no matter which card you choose, this move will terminate.

I found this problem interesting and wonder what if there are two people playing this, and who will have the winning strategies.

**Question:** With the same rule as above, two person, say $A$ and $B$ , moving alternately. Who will have winning strategy(if any)? The person start first or the second one? Or is there any other condition? The loser is the one that can no more move(no more card to choose).

more generaly,

**Problem:** If there are $n$ cards facing down, who has the winning strategy?

I don't know how to solve this, but I'm just curious about this one.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Your move consists of turning over two cards, so of course it terminates.  I assume you then have to move again...what causes the game to terminate?  When all the cards are face up?  When there aren't two consecutive face down cards?

Comment: @lulu: A move consists of flipping two neighboring cards, subject to the constraint that the _leftmost_ one of them must be face-down before the move. The game terminates when there is no valid move to pick.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  Ah, "right next to" means "the card to the right"...didn't guess that.  Thanks!

Comment: @lulu: It wasn't clear to me either, but the description at the beginning of the video is less ambiguous.

Comment: Is being the last player, i.e. the one terminating the game, the winner or the loser?

Comment: @FlorisClaassens: The usual convention in combinatorial game theory is that a player who has no legal move loses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial state of the game is

```
D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
```

The ending state is always

```
U U U U U U U U U U U U U U U U U U U U D
```

Now for each state let's count how many *face-down* cards there are in *even-numbered* positions on the table

```
D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
  ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
```

This number starts at $10$ and ends at $0$. In each move *exactly one* of these cards will be flipped so the number changes by $\pm 1$.

Therefore **there is always an even number of moves in the game**, no matter which strategy anyone follows.

---

This analysis generalizes easily to other numbers of cards. We see that who wins depends *only* on how many cards there are modulo 4.